# Polymer: form does not send paper-imput value and required attribute does not work

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I have the following component:

```
<link rel="import" href="./bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="./bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="./bower_components/iron-form/iron-form.html">

<dom-module id="my-form">
    <template>
        <b>Test</b>
        <form is="iron-form" id="form" method="post" action="/save">
            <paper-input name="name" value=""></paper-input>
            <button type="submit">submit!</button>
        </form>
    </template>

    <script>
        /**
        * @customElement
        * @polymer
        */
        class MyForm extends Polymer.Element {
            static get is() { return 'my-form'; }
            static get properties() {
                return { };
            }
        }
        window.customElements.define(MyForm.is, MyForm);
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

There are two problems:

1. Form is submitted when I click on submit button and required input
   is empty.
2. Nothing is sent when form is submitted.

What is happening?

Comment: take a look on the third example here https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-form/demo/demo/index.html

Comment: Thank you @Alon, but it does not work for me. I am using Polymer v2. Besides, I would like to avoid submit form when `paper-input` is `invalid`.

Comment: then use `paper-button` that invoke some function, where you `validate` iron-form and if `validate` returns true, then call `submit` on `iron-form` ? Is it what you want?

Comment: I can not make it work I think it's because I am using Polymer 2. `required` attribute works when I use Polymer 1 (but not `invalid`property)

Comment: @Amparo which version of the iron-form is in your bower.json ? can you tell ?

Comment: "iron-form": "^1.1.5"

Answer (score 0):

From the [What's new in 2.0](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/about_20):

> In addition, although they are supported in the specification, Polymer 2.0 does not currently support type-extension elements (`is=`).

This is the main reason why your code does not work. The `is` attribute is not supported anymore.

The current workaround for using `is` is the following:

```
// Before 2.0
<form /.../ is="iron-form"></form>

// After 2.0
<iron-form>
  <form /.../></form>
</iron-form>
```

Your code should then look like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="./bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="./bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="./bower_components/iron-form/iron-form.html">

<dom-module id="my-form">
    <template>
        <b>Test</b>
        <iron-form>
          <form id="form" method="post" action="/save">
              <paper-input name="name" value=""></paper-input>
              <button type="submit">submit!</button>
          </form>
        </iron-form>
    </template>

    <script>
        /**
        * @customElement
        * @polymer
        */
        class MyForm extends Polymer.Element {
            static get is() { return 'my-form'; }
            static get properties() {
                return { };
            }
        }
        window.customElements.define(MyForm.is, MyForm);
    </script>
</dom-module>
```